# Find the maximum depth of one directory in Linux

Tags: linux, tree, linux-kernel, filesystems, depth

By maximum depth, I mean the distance between the deepest descendant and this directory.

Is there a way to obtain the maximum depth of a directory without traverse all the file system tree ? Or which part in Linux Kernel code I could dig in to get this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to obtain the maximum depth of a directory without traverse all the file system tree ?

There is nothing in user-space except `readdir`/`getdents` which returns the entries of a single directory.

> Or which part in Linux Kernel code I could dig in to get this value?

Even in the kernel, VFS only requires an "iterate" function from each filesystem. Most filesystems are represented as a tree, and don't explicitly track this metric you request. There's no point.

You need to traverse the tree.